# p:layoutUnit ignore the margin-top

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

My question is quite simple. I'm using `PrimeFaces 3.0` and the layoutUnit component.

**Myxhtml**

```
<p:layout fullPage="true" locale="fr">
  <p:layoutUnit position="north" scrollable="false" resizable="false" size="60" locale="fr">
    <ui:insert>
      <ui:include src="../agenda/commons/menuView.xhtml"></ui:include>
    </ui:insert>
  </p:layoutUnit>
  <p:layoutUnit position="center" scrollable="false">
    ...
```

And the result is looking like this :

[image]

When i am inspecting the page, i have two `div` created and i can't edit them.

**Inspect code image**

[image]

Where do this `div` come from and how to edit them.

Comment: PrimeFaces 3.0 is very old, you should upgrade if you can. If you can't however you should try and override the style ui-layout-pane-north or a similar style. The Layout is styled in every pane to give you hooks.  As with all things CSS you will have to experiment with it.

Comment: In addition to the comment by @Melloware please note that p:layout is deprecated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801954/what-is-the-preferred-alternative-to-the-deprecated-primefaces-layout-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this post [How can I set the height in layoutUnit of primefaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765410/how-can-i-set-the-height-in-layoutunit-of-primefaces)

**myXHTML**

```
<style>
.westUnit {
height: 124px !important;
}

.westUnit1 {
height: 101px !important;
}
</style>


...
<p:layout fullPage="true" locale="fr" styleClass="westUnit">

    <p:layoutUnit position="north" scrollable="false" resizable="false"
        styleClass="westUnit1" size="60" locale="fr">

        <ui:insert>
            <ui:include src="../agenda/commons/menuView.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </ui:insert>

    </p:layoutUnit>
 ...
```